# Changing Kivy Spinner values dynamically

Tags: spinner, kivy, kivy-language

I´m looking for a way to set the values of a Kivy Spinner depending on the text chosen from the parent spinner. The problem is that I have defined both spinners in kv language. I´m not sure if the approach would be to destroy the second spinner each time a new value is chosen from the first one, then regenerate it (if so I have no idea how to do that because of the kv code), or if there would be a way to dynamically update the "values" of the second spinner based on an on_text procedure updating the list.

In all cases the below code does not work. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 80
            spacing: 20
            Spinner:
                id: spinner_1
                text: '< Select >'
                values: root.pickType
                on_text: root.updateSubSpinner(spinner_1.text)
            Spinner:
                id: spinner_2
                text: '< Select >'
                values: root.pickSubType

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            on_press: root.onExit()
            text: 'Exit'
            font_size: 50

''')

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.buildLists()
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def buildLists(self):
        self.pickType = ['Select','#1','#2','#3']
        self.pickSubType = ['Select'] 

    def updateSubSpinner(self,text):
        if text == '#1':
            self.pickSubType.extend('A'+'B')
        elif text == '#2':
            self.pickSubType.extend('P'+'Q')
        else:
            self.pickSubType.extend('Y'+'Z')

    def onExit(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reference the child spinner values list, not the `pickSubType` list, which isn't even bound to it. Example:

```
def updateSubSpinner(self, text):
    self.ids.spinner_2.text = 'Select'

    if text == '#1':
        self.ids.spinner_2.values = ['A', 'B']
    elif text == '#2':
        self.ids.spinner_2.values = ['P', 'Q']
    else:
        self.ids.spinner_2.values = ['Y', 'Z']
```

Writing `values: root.pickSubType` doesn't bind the `pickSubType` to the `values`, if the first isn't a `ListProperty`. You could upgrade it to a `ListProperty` if you like, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the list was bound to the spinner, although it clearly seems to only provide the spinner its initial values, so I was working on the wrong object in the end. Thanks for the help again,.